# Query latest post from each category

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there are quite a few questions about wp_queries but none are quite answering what I want.

I was wrecking my brain on how to query 1 most recent post from each of my blog categories but using the [] notation instead of an array:

```
function get_latest_posts($query_args, $grid_name) {
  $categories = array(1593, 1594, 1595, 1596, 1597);

  if ($grid_name == 'get_latest_posts') {
    $query_args['posts_per_page'] = 1;
  } 
  return $query_args;
}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'get_latest_posts', 10, 2);
// This returns one post but just one post, not one post per category
```

Using this style of query_args instead of a "traditional" array, would it be possible to have something like:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
  return $query_args;
}
// Something like this would be awesome ❥
```

Thank you in advance! Sorry I'm such a newbie.

Comment: There are two different types of arrays, but both are still arrays. `[1593]` (array) and `['category' => 1593]` (associative array). Which are you talking about?

Comment: The ['key'] => value one! Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: You loop through associative arrays with `foreach` like you posted. If you want to generate a list of the first post of every category *before outputting*, then you'll have to put everything inside your own associative array before using `return`. You should only `return` after the foreach is done looping through each category by putting `return` it after the `foreach`. Your return value can be your associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<?php
function post_from_each_category(){
  $categories = array(1593, 1594, 1595, 1596, 1597);
  $posts = [];
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $posts[] = get_posts([
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'tax_query' => [
        [
          'taxonomy' => 'category',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => [$category],
        ],
      ],
    ]);
  }
  return $posts;
}
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. I modified the code a little bit to work with "The Grid" plugin (added the if grid name statement), but it doesn't seem to want to work, and I am a little confused as how I could test or get some kind of output of what I am doing wrong.